# How to plot uptime of an application using downtime and dates?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, python-3.8

In a CSV file, I have dates, downtime, and incident numbers of my application.  Based on the below data I have to plot a graph of my application uptime using Python. Uptime for the last 7 days, Uptime for the last 30 days, and uptime for the last 90 days.

| date | downtime(hrs) | incident |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-05 | 2 | abc123 |
| 2022-10-05 | 3 | abc124 |
| 2022-09-01 | 4 | abc100 |
| 2022-08-26 | 8 | abc99 |
| 2022-08-24 | 5 | abc98 |
| 2022-07-15 | 6 | abc90 |
| 2022-06-09 | 4 | abc85 |

I can read this data using pandas and I am able to plot downtime by incident using the below method.

```
downtime_by_incident = data.groupby(["date", "incident"])['downtime].sum().unstack().plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, xlabel="", legend=False).get_figure()
downtime_by_incident.savefig("downtime_by_incident.jpg", bbox_inches = "tight")
```

But I am unable to calculate and plot the uptime of my application. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What should the uptime plot look like? Please provide an expected output based on the sample data.

Comment: That is the challenge. I am unable to visualize how to represent this data over a graph. I was trying to visualize using a line graph but could not draw

Comment: I would use a bar code plot. You could invert by exploding to times and then inverting.

Comment: I guess my question is do you want to fill in all the missing dates on the current dateframe as I assume your application was up and working as expected durning those dates.

Comment: yes, that is correct. Application was up and running during the missing dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is creating a second dataset to track uptime, complementary to your current dataset which tracks downtime.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''date   downtime(hrs)   incident
2022-10-05  2   abc123
2022-10-05  3   abc124
2022-09-01  4   abc100
2022-08-26  8   abc99
2022-08-24  5   abc98
2022-07-15  6   abc90
2022-06-09  4   abc85'''), sep='\t')

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max(),freq='d')}).assign(tot_hours=24)

df2 = pd.merge(df2, df[['date', 'downtime(hrs)']].groupby('date').sum().reset_index(), how='left')

df2['uptime'] = df2['tot_hours'] - df2['downtime(hrs)'].fillna(0)

#if there's any negative downtime, impute to zero
df2['uptime'] = np.where(df2['uptime']<0, 0, df2['uptime'])

fig = px.line(df2,
          x='date',
          y='uptime')

fig.show()
```

[image: figure]

With the actual dataset, you could find the latest uptimes like this:

```
for n in [7,30,90]:
    n_days_ago = pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()-pd.Timedelta(n, unit='d')
    today = pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()
    df2.loc[df2['date'].between(n_days_ago, today), 'uptime'].sum()

#output
0.0
0.0
1370.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code.  Sorry to ask another question, If the same day two incidents occur and both probably took around 18 and 20 hours respectively. When we plot the graph point for that day by reducing from 24 the value actually goes to minus whereas in reality, it should only go to 0. How can I handle that with above code?

Comment: Good question. The easiest way is to impute any negative to zero. I updated the answer to account for that possibility.

Comment: Thanks a ton. One last question(sorry, I am very new to pandas).  How can i restrict the graph to just 30 days? in Other words plot the graph of the last 30 days' uptime

Comment: No problem. You could do `fig = px.line(df2[df2['date'].between(pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()-pd.Timedelta(30, unit='d'), pd.to_datetime('today').normalize())],
          x='date',
          y='uptime')`

Comment: or `fig = px.line(df2[df2['date']>=pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()-pd.Timedelta(30, unit='d')],
          x='date',
          y='uptime')`

Comment: Sorry, one more question, How easy is it to convert to % wise uptime ? for eg 7 days % uptime, 30 days % uptime etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
# convert to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
# groupby date and sum downtime then merge on a new Frame you create
# that fills in the missing dates
m = df.groupby('date')['downtime(hrs)'].sum().reset_index().merge(pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(df['date'].min(),
                                                                                             df['date'].max()),
                                                                               columns=['date']),
                                                                  on='date', how='right').fillna(0)
# calculate the uptime (24 hours - downtime hours) for each day
m['uptime'] = 24 - m['downtime(hrs)']
# bar plot
m[['date', 'uptime']].set_index('date').plot(kind='bar', figsize=(20,10))

# line plot
m[['date', 'uptime']].set_index('date')['uptime'].plot(figsize=(20,10))

# stacked bar plot
m.set_index('date').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(20,10))
```

[image]

Note that you should probably update this line:

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max()), columns=['date'])
```

to be today and not the last day in your first frame

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), datetime.datetime.today()), columns=['date'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code.  Sorry to ask another question, If the same day two incidents occur and both probably took around 18 and 20 hours respectively. When we plot the graph point for that day by reducing from 24 the value actually goes to minus whereas in reality, it should only go to 0. How can I handle that with the above code?